# MaterUI Table component trigger onRowSelection event and unselect all when clicking anywhere

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-ui

Take the official table component example: [MaterialUI Table example](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/table)

1. Tick one checkbox
2. Click anywhere out of the table component

The checkbox is unchecked.

I did some tests locally. It seems when some item(s) are ticked in Table component, you can click anywhere outside of the Table component to trigger a **onRowSelection** event which returns a empty array

#### Question

I know it might be by design, but can I change the default behavior, use "all" checkbox to control tick/untick all items in table? So the checkbox won't be cleaned up after a random mouse click ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the deselectOnClickaway property of TableBody to false (default is true)